# Ruby questions about web layer layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make a URL like `<a href="/formats/formats.html.erb">Link Title</a>` from within my application.  What is the file that I need to edit to link this URL to a controller and then a view?

Also, I am still working my way through this tutorial:

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

and I am wondering when they do something like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://example.com/main.css" %>
```

is that supposed to live in the `application.html.erb` file or the `index.html.erb` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the file that I need to edit to link this url to a controller and then a view?

`routes.rb`

See [the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

> is that supposed to live in the application.html.erb file or the index.html.erb file?

The simple answer is: application.html.erb, inside the head section.  There are ways of injecting view template stuff into the head, but if you're just starting out, stick with application.html.erb.